Is $D:\mathscr X(M) \times \Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$ a (1-1) tensor field or (2,1)-tensor field?
I have tried to look in many pleases and books, but I can't figure out why the following must be so
If $D:\mathscr X(M) \times \Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$ is a $C^\infty(M)$-linear in both a vector field $X$ and a section $s$, $D$ defines a section of the bundle $T^*M \otimes \text{End}(E)$, meaning:
$$
D \in \Gamma(T^*M \otimes \text{End}(E)).
$$
so it behaves like a $(1,1)$-tensor.
If $E$ had been the tangent budle TM, the conclusion is that  $
D$ defines a $(2,1)$ tensor field, which if I'm not mistaken would be denoted as  $\Gamma( T^{(2,1)}M)$
So generalizing this to the case above i would have expected that also D above would be a $(2,1)$-tensor field. How on Earth is it a $(1,1)$-tensor field?  After all vector fields are sections when $E=TM$
